# In what cases are posts collecting information about multiple versions okay?

Tags: discussion

I've seen answers before that are updated/edited to add information about new versions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35775094/2016165)).

Googling about a problem with Swift returned a question on Stack Overflow and [one of its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31415263/2016165) fixed my problem.

Said answer only answers the problem for Swift 2 though, there are separate answers for Swift 3 and 4 (none for Swift 5, which is the latest version).
Following the example of other edited posts I edited the question to add the code for version 3 and 4 (linking the source), plus my own for version 5, and a short explanation what the code actually does.

This edit [was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23028157). I understand that my edit added a lot of information but I don't understand how it *"intended to address the author of the post"* or *"deviates from the original intent of the post"*.

So my question: In what case it it okay to add information about later versions - hence: code that does the same thing but only works with a later version of the programming language? Is it ever okay to add this type of information if you aren't the author of the answer?

Comment: This is an area where the rules and guidelines are contradicting. On the one hand they want to update outdated answers, but on the other hand they want to avoid editing existing posts and that one writes their own answer instead. So you can update your own posts for newer versions or create a new answer if the existing answer isn't from you. This also shows that Stack Overflow doesn't handle solution updates for newer versions that well.

Comment: Most of the code snippets you added for different versions look nearly identical. Stack Overflow is not intended as a snippet repository. It is not necessary to have copy-paste ready code for every version, configuration, and phase of the moon. If you explain the concept well, and provide a representative code example, that is sufficient for anyone in our target audience to figure out how to apply that to a later version. If there’s a significant change you worry someone wouldn’t be able to figure out, a simple sentence calling that out is sufficient.

Comment: @Tom Exactly where the guidelines say to avoid editing post? The help center, says that if you can improve a post, edit it.

Comment: @Braiam Pretty funny that you ask that. You're here for several years and quite active on meta and you want to tell me you missed all the meta discussions about rejected edits regarding additional information in existing posts? I guess you tried to make a joke.

Comment: @Tom no, really, I need to find each one of them to beat sensibility into those posts.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, they're nearly identical - that's the problem. There seem to be small changes between the different versions of Swift. For some of them Xcode suggests "... was replaced with ..." with a "Fix" button but this doesn't work for everything, which then gets really frustrating because Xcode doesn't even hint at what's wrong exactly. So for those people who aren't Swift-experts it's important to have info about newer versions too imo.

Comment: @Tom Do edits like mine usually get rejected? Then, even if there weren't any rules about this (are there?) this would at least tell me how this kind of stuff is usually handled.

Comment: Is it okay to link the other versions in the first post or is that basically the same "bad" thing as directly adding the code with a "source" link?

Answer (score 2):

If it is your own or wiki answer it is fine (and desirable) to add new variants for new versions.

If it is someone else's answer and not a wiki then post new answer. You may consider if adding note about “this applies to version 2-5, for 6+ check other answers”.

If you really feel that a new answer would not be useful you can try to coordinate with author of the post by commenting like “I want to add solutions for new version. Are you okay with editing this post or I should add new answer?“ Or just see if they accept your edits (authors can see rejected changes and approve them anyway)

As for the general decision of adding more information to existing Q&A or asking a new one for new version - usually multiple versions in same question are fine. There are known cases when new versions are really new products (like Python 2 vs 3, Angular 1 vs 2) where people are expected to search for version specific solutions- separate Q&A are fine for those.

Comment: "you can try to coordinate with author of the post by comment" Shog specifically called out about this kind of coordination as a waste of time. If the author isn't happy about the edit, it can revert it back. But note, that even then, if the post was improved to be an stellar one, a CM could just force the post to be the best version of itself.

Comment: The author hasn't been active on Stackexchange in a month and hasn't posted anything since 2015, which probably rules out asking him. What to do in this case? My intention of the edit was to have information about all versions in a single answer. Currently there's an answer for version 2, 3 and 4 (with various votes, so not even directly below each other), so creating an extra answer for version 5 would make them 4 posts for basically the same thing.